# Converting NMEA to JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

**Hi can someone help me convert the following NMEA sentences using javascript? I need to display the Lat/long of each sentence in JSON format. Thanks**

```
$GPGLL,3854.929,N,07902.501,W,150359.979,V*3D
$GPGLL,3854.929,N,07902.503,W,150400.979,V*34
$GPGLL,3854.928,N,07902.504,W,150401.979,V*33
$GPGLL,3854.927,N,07902.506,W,150402.979,V*3D
$GPGLL,3854.927,N,07902.508,W,150403.979,V*32
$GPGLL,3854.926,N,07902.509,W,150404.979,V*35
$GPGLL,3854.927,N,07902.511,W,150405.979,V*3C
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the GPS.js library from here: https://www.xarg.org/2016/07/using-gps-with-node-js-and-javascript/

```
var gps = new GPS;

var sentence = '$GPGGA,224900.000,4832.3762,N,00903.5393,E,1,04,7.8,498.6,M,48.0,M,,0000*5E';

gps.on('data', function(parsed) {

  console.log(parsed);
});

gps.update(sentence);
```